# Database migrations in docker swarm mode

Tags: database, docker, database-migration, docker-swarm

I have an application that consists of simple Node app and Mongo db. I wonder, how could I run database migrations in docker swarm mode?

Without swarm mode I run migrations by stopping first the old version of application, running one-off migration command with new version of application and then finally starting a new version of app:

```
# Setup is roughly the following
$ docker network create appnet
$ docker run -d --name db --net appnet db:1
$ docker run -d --name app --net appnet -p 80:80 app:1

# Update process
$ docker stop app && docker rm app
$ docker run --rm --net appnet app:2 npm run migrate
$ docker run -d --name app --net appnet -p 80:80 app:2
```

Now I'm testing the setup in docker swarm mode so that I could easily scale `app`. The problem is that in swarm mode one can't start containers in swarm network and thus I can't reach the db to run migrations:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
6jtmtihmrcjl        appnet              overlay             swarm

# Trying to replicate the manual migration process in swarm mode
$ docker service scale app=0
$ docker run --rm --net appnet app:2 npm run migrate
docker: Error response from daemon: swarm-scoped network (appnet) is not compatible with `docker create` or `docker run`. This network can only be used by a docker service.
```

I don't want to run the migration command during `app` startup either, as there might be several instances launching and that would potentially screw the database. Automatic migrations are scary, so I want to avoid them at all costs.

Do you have any idea how to implement manual migration step in docker swarm mode?

**Edit**

I found out a **dirty** hack that allows to replicate the original workflow. Idea is to create a new service with custom command and remove it when one of its tasks is finished. This is far from pleasant usage, better alternatives are more than welcome!

```
$ docker service scale app=0
$ docker service create --name app-migrator --network appnet app:2 npm run migrate

# Check when the first app-migrator task is finished and check its output
$ docker service ps app-migrator
$ docker logs <container id from app-migrator>
$ docker service rm app-migrator

# Ready to update the app
$ docker service update --image app:2 --replicas 2 app
```

Comment: This  use case keeps coming up. There's a Github issue with the discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23880). I personally use a generic "maintenance" service and call `docker service update ...` to force it to spawn new tasks (containers) for the requested work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can fix this problem by making your overlay network, appnet, attachable. This can be accomplished with the following command:

```
docker network create --driver overlay --attachable appnet
```

This should fix the swarm-scoped network error and and allow you to run migrations

Comment: Yes! Docker 1.13 brought us this `--attachable` flag, which allows running single containers attached to swarm overlay network. Sweet! I tried it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed tricky situation, though I think running the migration during startup might be the the final piece of the puzzle.

The way I do it right now (though not very elegant, it works), is using a `message queue` (I'm using `redis`), on app startup, it will send a message to a the `queue`, informing it that the `migration` task needs to be run. At the other end of the `queue`, I have a `listener app` that will process the `queue` and run the `migration` task. The migration task would only run once, since there's only a single instance of the `listener` running it sequentially. So essentially I'm just using the `queue` & the `listener app` to make sure that the `migration` task runs only once.

Comment: Tricky situation, indeed :) Maybe your solution would be the way to go for now, if I had that kind of infrastructure already in place. But in my case it is just too heavy solution for launching some random administrative commands against db. I edited my question and added one dirty way to run random commands in swarm network. That solution is still far from acceptable, but it's best I have in my hands now. Thanks for your contribution!